# How do I efficiently determine the scale factor of two parallel vectors?

Tags: c++

I have two three-dimensional non-zero vectors which I know to be parallel, and thus I can multiply each component of one vector by a constant to obtain the other. In order to determine this constant, I can take any of the fields from both vectors and divide them by one another to obtain the scale factor.

For example:

```
vec3 vector1(1.0, 1.5, 2.0);
vec3 vector2(2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
float scaleFactor = vector2.x / vector1.x; // = 2.0
```

Unfortunately, picking the same field (say the x-axis) every time risks the divisor being zero.

Dividing the lengths of the vectors is not possible either because it does not take a negative scale factor into account.

Is there an efficient means of going about this which avoids zero divisions?

Comment: Just pick the first entry of `vector1` that's sufficiently large?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I was mainly wondering whether there was some trickery possible with comparisons against NaN values so I can get away with some min/max instructions as opposed to going full-out with branching. Though come to think of it that does also cost additional divisions, which probably are more expensive than branches anyway.

Comment: Given the number of elements is constant and small, you could also pick the one element of `vector1` that's closest to 1 (in `abs`). This will probably reduce potential rounding error in some corner cases, may or may not apply to your data.

Comment: *"Though come to think of it that does also cost additional divisions, which probably are more expensive than branches anyway."* Probably, yes. But if this stuff is critical, measure, don't guess.

Comment: Do you know the length of *one* of the vectors? Or is one of those vectors constantly being compared to many other vectors so computing its length is relatively cheap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So we want something that:

1- has no branching

2- avoids division by zero

3- ensures the largest possible divider

These requirements are achieved by the ratio of two dot-products:

```
(v1 * v2) / (v2 * v2)
= 
(v1.x*v2.x + v1.y*v2.y + v1.z*v2.z) / (v2.x*v2.x + v2.y*v2.y + v2.z*v2.z)
```

In the general case where the dimension is not a (compile time) constant, both numerator and denominator can be computed in a single loop.

Comment: The worst case is that all components but one are zero (e.g. z-axis aligned in 3D). This shows you potentially need all components, and in a non-branching solution that means you _always_ need all components. This answer is the effective way to achieve that. If the dimension is high and not a compile-time constant, and the compiler can't use loop unrolling, it's probably best to use a single loop instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much, this.

```
inline float scale_factor(const vec3& v1, const vec3& v2, bool* fail)
{
    *fail = false;
    float eps = 0.000001;
    if (std::fabs(vec1.x) > eps)
        return vec2.x / vec1.x;
    if (std::fabs(vec1.y) > eps)
        return vec2.y / vec1.y;
    if (std::fabs(vec1.z) > eps)
        return vec2.z / vec1.z;

    *fail = true;
    return -1;
}
```

Also, one can think of getting 2 sums of elements, and then getting a scale factor with a single division. You can get sum effectively by using IPP's  ippsSum_32f, for example, as it is calculated using SIMD instructions.

But, to be honest, I doubt that you can really improve these methods. Either sum all -> divide or branch -> divide will provide you with the solution pretty close to the best.

Answer (score 0):

To minimize the relative error, use the largest element:

```
if (abs(v1.x) > abs(v1.y) && abs(v1.x) > abs(v1.z))
    return v2.x / v1.x;
else if (abs(v1.y) > abs(v1.x) && abs(v1.y) > abs(v1.z))
    return v2.y / v1.y;
else
    return v2.z / v1.z;
```

This code assumes that `v1` is not a zero vector.